# How to open object(macros) and use the form in it using command button?

Tags: vba, excel

**Hi GUYS** , I will explain my problem:

1- I use object command in excel to bring another excel file see image(1)[object_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB9dI.png)

2- I want to make command button which links to the object

3-image (2) show the worksheets and forms note when I close the book, the object's book change [image all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnZQp.png)

so what I want is when I click the command button in my first excel it will open the form and allow me to change in the second excel.

this is my code

```
Private Sub CO1_Click()

Workbooks("Book3").Worksheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.Value = True
Application.Run Workbooks("Book3").Worksheets("Sheet1").OnAction

trainUserForm.Show

End Sub
```

please, guys, i need this to finish my work and thx :)